# $l_p$ with $0<p<1$ is a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $0<p<1$ and $l_p$ the sequence space, where $x \in l_p \implies\sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i|^p <\infty. $

Trying to show that $l_p$ is a vector space I tried to proof that $x,y \in l_p$ implies $x+y \in l_p$ , so, I must show that

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i+y_i|^p < \infty$ (1)

In a document found this lemma

$|\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i |^p \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^p$  (2)

whitout demonstration just to say that

$|x_i+y_i|^p\le|x_i|^p+|y_i|^p$ (3)

in (1). Could someone tell me how to proof some of these inequalities ( (2) or (3) ) ?

Sorry for my english or other mistakes, is my first question here. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ the inequality (*) $\vert x+y\vert^p\leq \vert x\vert^p+\vert y\vert^p$ obviously holde true. If $x,y\not =0$ we may assume first that $0<y\leq x$. Then $\vert x+y\vert^p=x^p(1+t)^p$ where $0<t=\frac{y}{x}\leq 1$. The function $f$, $f(s):=(1+s)^p-1-s^p$ is decreasing, as may be seen by considering $f'$. So $f(t)\leq f(1)=2^p-2<0$. This implies that $(x+y)^p=x^p(1+t)^p\leq x^p(1+t^p)=x^p+y^p$. The general case follows by observing that $\vert x+y\vert^p\leq (\vert x\vert+\vert y\vert)^p$.